# Custom task Executor or "am I reinventing the wheel?"

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, java-8, java-stream

I'm trying to create an utility class that will be able to handle bundles of runnables and execute them in different combinations (sync, async).

For example : imagine that this is a json like representation of a composite task. "[]" are keeping async tasks and "{}" are keeping synced tasks.

```
[
    task,
    [task, task, task],
    {task, task, [task, task]}
]
```

and this is (will be) implemented in a method chaining manner :

```
fromAsyncTasks(
    from(runnable),
    fromSyncedTasks(from(runnable), from(runnable), from(runnable)),
    fromAsyncTasks(from(runnable), from(runnable), fromAsyncTasks(from(runnable), from(runnable)))
).execute();
```

as you probably understood .execute() is calling recursively other tasks execute() in a sync or async manner. Also Task interface supports terminate() to stop (interrupt a task) thus if I keep a reference to those tasks I'll be able to terminate them.

So the question #1 is : is there any tools, libraries providing at least this functionality?

and #2 : if I use streams for paralel (async case) execution how do I terminate them?

```
tasks.parallelStream().forEach(Runnable::run)
```

Comment: [invoke a bunch of task that should complete](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#invokeAll(java.util.Collection)) or [invoke a bunch of task that should stop once one completed](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#invokeAny(java.util.Collection)) or [build composed tasks](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinTask.html), …

Comment: @Holger I do know about Executor interface, but the thing is that there will be lot of business logic that will dynamically execute some tasks (sync or async or in combination) and If we use Executors code hardly will be readable.

Comment: For clarification: Do you mean _in parallel_ by _async_, and _sequentially_ by _sync_?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since Java 8, the class [java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html) is part of the standard library. This class provides basically everything you need to build what you want.

To directly support your use case, you need some kind of abstraction, that is either a `Runnable`, a synchronous list of tasks, or an asynchronous list of tasks. In the following code, this abstraction is class `Task`:

```
interface Task {
    CompletableFuture<Void> execute(
        CompletableFuture<Void> f, Executor e);
}
```

Following are three factory methods to create the three different kind of tasks:

```
static Task wrap(Runnable runnable) {
    return (f, e) -> f.thenRunAsync(runnable, e);
}
static Task sync(Task... tasks) {
    return (f, e) -> {
        for (Task task : tasks) {
            f = task.execute(f, e);
        }
        return f;
    };
}
static Task async(Task... tasks) {
    return (f, e) -> tasks.length == 0 ? f :
        CompletableFuture.allOf(
        Arrays.stream(tasks)
        .map(t -> t.execute(f, e))
        .toArray(CompletableFuture[]::new));
}
```

Now, you can easily create arbitrary nested structures of runnable, sync and async tasks, and execute them with an arbitrary `Executor`. Here is a short example:

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    Task task = sync(
        wrap(() -> log("1")),
        async(
            wrap(() -> log("A")),
            wrap(() -> log("B")),
            wrap(() -> log("C"))),
        wrap(() -> log("2")),
        wrap(() -> log("3")));
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);
    task.execute(CompletableFuture.completedFuture(null), executor).join();
    executor.shutdown();
}
```

Comment: Thank you I didn't know about CompletableFuture and ComplationStage interfaces.

Comment: If I wrote this implementation it would take several classes, rather this implementation is just beautiful, but code looks like majic to me, altough I understood what it does I'm sure Id never think that way, maybe because I never used functional programming or any closure focused language. Can you recommend any books or articles that could advance lambda way thinking?

Comment: I've used this, but i'm not sure how do I get a value from completed task?

Comment: @Vach: There are no return values in your original code, so I also omitted them, because it makes the code a bit more complex (in particular regarding _async_ execution). Still, the type parameter of the `CompletableFuture` specifies the return type, and the method `join` returns the result.

Comment: @Vach: I am not aware of any book, that covers above usage of Java 8 features. The code is very specific to Java 8. A general book about lambdas won't help. Maybe there will something like _More Effective Java_ in the future.

Answer (score 1):

there must be reasons why some tasks are executed after others. That reasons should be represented somehow - as messages or signals. When they are explicitly represented, then you your json-like notation can be converted to a [Dataflow diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_flow_diagram).

For a library to execute dataflow diagrams, look at my [df4j2](https://github.com/rfqu/df4j2/tree/master/df4j-core).